# Protecting I2C bus with diodes

Tags: i2c, protection, schottky

I'm trying to add some protection to an I2C bus, and keep getting an unexpected result.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpho5t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In principle, I'd expect this to clamp the signal (which I simulate with a sine wave and a small resistor) to between -0.6 to 5.6V. In the simulation, this looks good, but in reality (using LSM115JE3 diodes), the bus signal cannot reach above 3.6V -- which coincidentally is \$5V - (2 \times 0.7V)\$.

Any idea what might cause such an effect?

Comment: Give us a schematic of the circuit you actually measured. What chips were attached? What pull-up resistors? What power supplies were supplying each of those chips?

Comment: What is the amplitude of the sine wave? Did you double-check V2 before R1? It will only clamp if driven high enough in the first place.

Maybe you are mixed up on the diode pinout? Not sure if you are using a dual diode package or two singles. But if I remember right, there are endless varieties of dual diodes with common cathode, common anode, and cathode to anode all being somewhat common.

Comment: Oh, I see you used singles. That is a beefy Schottky diode (LSM115JE3). It should clamp much lower than 5.6V. Maybe 5.1 or 5.2V. Certainly no more than 5.3V.

Comment: Note that your schematic shows (and LSM115 are) Shottky diodes. The forward voltage is only 0.2 V for 1 A forward current. So you should expect clamping limits around -0.2 and +5.2 V.

Comment: Most likely answer: There is some chip attached to the line with a 3.0 to 3.3 V power supply and its ESD protection diode is clamping at 3.6 V. But without a schematic of what you actually measured, how can we be sure?

Comment: Without the diodes, the bus correctly reaches voltages between 0V and 5V -- same if I disconnect the GND connection to the diodes.

Comment: I'm aware the diodes are a bit overkill -- but these happened the be lying around.

Comment: The actual circuit is an Arduino, writing fixed values to the bus, instead of the source in the above circuit. I'd have to repeat the actual measurement and take a picture of the scope, I can possibly do that tonight.

Comment: If the diodes are definitely causing the problem, try a different diode. Maybe they are not what you think they are (did you double-check the markings?), or are defective or whatever. If you don't have any other diodes lying around, use a BJT as a diode. Just as an experiment to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the datasheet [datasheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Microsemi%20PDFs/LSM115J.pdf), it seems like those diodes can have a significant reverse current -- up to several milliamps at 5V if they're warm. They also have a nontrival junction capacitance, on the order of 100 pF.

The main question is whether this is an AC problem or a DC problem. If the DC level is correctly pulled up to 5V but the rise times are too slow during transmission, try using stiffer pull-ups, no more than 1000 ohms. (You do have pull-up resistors, right? You need pull-ups for I2C.) If the DC level is stuck at 3.6V, try measuring the diode current with a multimeter to make sure they're not broken. You could also try removing the 100 ohm resistor.